# Is there a way to pre-fill the body of a new question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

JSFiddle and Codepen have Form-Post endpoints to start an a new entry with pre-filled content. Is there a similar Form-Post endpoint or other method to do the same for Stack Overflow (**NOT** api.stackexchange.com)

JSFiddle Docs: https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/api/prefill/

CodePen Docs: https://docs.jsfiddle.net/api/display-a-fiddle-from-post

Both use a `<form>`. The JSFiddle one the form has multiple fields. The codepen one they use a single JSON string inside one field. The JSON string has the various fields.

Stack Overflow allows setting the title and tags using a query string. Example:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=React&tags=react,javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=React&tags=react,javascript)

But setting a body does not pre-fill in the body.

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=React&body=code-goes-here&tags=react,javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=React&body=code-goes-here&tags=react,javascript)

Is there a way to pre-fill the body of a new question?

Comment: You're talking about prefilling the ask question form with some content, right?

Comment: Yes, pre-filling the ask question form with some content.

Comment: Corresponding post on MSE: [Prepopulating Stack Overflow's "ask" form with query params](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187291/335251)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to populate the body portion.

As you've noticed, you can pre-fill the title and tags using the appropriate query strings, but there is no query string that can pre-fill the body of the question.

This is by design. Users need to write the own body of their question.

See: [Prepopulating StackOverflow's "ask" form with query params](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187291/prepopulating-stackoverflows-ask-form-with-query-params) (on the global Meta)

Comment: how sad. So many closed questions could be prevented if an API site could pre-populate questions about their API with appropriate boilerplate saving time for both questioners and answerers

Comment: How is getting people to post boilerplate going to solve any of our problems?

Comment: In the tags I follow 6 out 7 users don't know how to post a snippet and end up posting direct links into their own projects which questions are supposed to closed. Even knowing how to post a snippet they wouldn't know how to include the library. By giving them a pre-populated snippet they'd have an example to expand on. You might as well ask why codepen and jsfiddle have these options. Because they're useful!

Comment: @gman: the template project shows that if you give people placeholders to fill in, some of them will post the placeholders.

Comment: Beyond halfer's point (which is absolutely true), CodePen and JSFiddle have somewhat different goals to Stack Overflow. In particular, their goals are to get people up and running as quickly as possible. Giving them a pre-filled template, where they can simply click "Run" and see *something* immediately, thus makes sense. That isn't true for Stack Overflow. We're not trying to get people to post questions as quickly as possible, by doing as little work as possible.